# load fixtures from unittest module

Tags: python, fixtures, python-unittest

in Django is posible load json files as fixtures for test.

```
class test_with_fixtures(LiveServerTestCase):
    fixtures = ['user-data.json']
```

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/topics/testing/tools/#liveservertestcase

in python unittest module, exist a way so easy to load initial data for test ?

or, what other python test module have this characteristics ?

Comment: In django, you have a test database which can be initialized from fixture files. While using `unittest` you should use `setUp`, `tearDown`, `setUpClass`, `tearDownClass`, `setUpModule`, `tearDownModule` methods for initializing the data.